# Any problem if we use the word 'iPhone' in our App Name?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

**Would that be a reason for rejection of our app, if we use the word 'iPhone' or 'iPad' in our app name?**

For example, names like - 'My iPhone Style' or 'New iPad style'.

I am going to submit an App soon and little confused about this problem. The thing is, It is necessary to use the word iPhone in my app name to get identified the purpose of my app.
Please help me. Thanx in advance. :-)

Comment: Yes, probably. But you're free to try it, you just might have to choose a new name.

Comment: Why would you do that, anyway? That's an awfully long name, and your users know they are on an iPhone or iPad when they are using it... do they really need the reminder in the name?

Comment: Actually those names above given were just sample names. But my real app name needs the word iPhone to indicate the purpose of App. Without the word iphone in name , app can't say what its for. Anyway Thanx :-)

Comment: I am about to do the same thing - @S.Philip, did you have any success or failure regarding this issue?

Comment: @Ash . Actually, I left that idea and used some other name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app will be rejected for two reasons:

1. You do not have the right to use Apple's trademark. It's the same reason you can't call your app "Mickey Mouse Clock" or "Microsoft AwesomeNote" or whatever. Review section 8 of the [**App Store Review Guidelines**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) on the use of third-party trademarks, then the [**Apple Trademark List**](https://www.apple.com/legal/trademark/appletmlist.html) to see what trademarks they hold. iPhone and iPad are most certainly included.
2. You cannot use their trademarks in your product name, and you cannot use any of their trademarked names in a way that could imply the product had Apple's approval or was from Apple. See the [**Guidelines for Using Apple Trademarks and Copyrights**](https://www.apple.com/legal/trademark/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html), specifically items 1 and 5 in the Unauthorized Use of Apple Trademarks section.

Answer (score 0):

looking on the app store I see plenty of examples of X App for iPhone and x App for iPad, however all of these names, unlike My iPhone Style, make more or less clear what the app does and use "for iPhone" or something  to distinguish between versions.

Comment: Actually those names above given were just sample names. Thanx for the answer :-)